# Implementing TableSorter to include the price in Millions and Billions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I am using the TableSorter plugin in jquery. However one of the column in the table is listed as follows :

---

### Market Cap

- $12M
- $1.2B
- $3B
- $34M

And the TableSorter is not working properly. Any idea how to fix it. Any other plugin which I can use ?

P.S: I cannot do-away with suffix  M & B. So I cannot Mathematically modify the Market cap so that it works properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this fiddle out](http://jsfiddle.net/WbchW/)

Looking through [the docs of TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html) it looks like you can create a custom parser.

Created this simply parser and it looks to do the trick

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id
        id: 'marketcap',
        is: function(s) {
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s) {
            s = s.replace('$','');
            if(s.indexOf('M') >-1){
                s = parseInt(s)* 1000000;
            }else if(s.indexOf('B') >-1){
                s = parseInt(s)* 1000000000;
            }

            // format your data for normalization
            return s;
        },
        // set type, either numeric or text
        type: 'numeric'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Amin's answer is good. Also with "K" or it can be used with any other measure. So the complete example would be:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id
    id: 'marketcap',
    is: function(s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
        s = s.replace('$','');
        if(s.indexOf('K') >-1){
            s = parseInt(s)* 1000;
        }else if(s.indexOf('M') >-1){
            s = parseInt(s)* 1000000;
        }else if(s.indexOf('B') >-1){
            s = parseInt(s)* 1000000000;
        }

        // format your data for normalization
        return s;
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text
    type: 'numeric'
});

$(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            3: {
                sorter:'marketcap'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

For an html like:

```
<table cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter">             
<thead>> 
    <tr> 

        <th>english</th> 
        <th>japanese</th> 
        <th>calculus</th> 
        <th>Market Cap</th> 
    </tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
    <tr> 

        <td>80</td> 
        <td>70</td> 
        <td>75</td> 
        <td>$34M</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 

        <td>90</td> 
        <td>88</td> 
        <td>100</td> 
        <td>$1.2B</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 

        <td>85</td> 
        <td>95</td> 
        <td>80</td> 
        <td>$12M</td> 
    </tr> 
</tbody>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Missing something!!
In the example above one of the values is $1.2B, then parseInt(s) will convert it to integer.
Consider using instead: parseFloat() & toFixed() for decimals to consider

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id
    id: 'marketcap',
    is: function(s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
        s = s.replace('$','');
        if(s.indexOf('K') >-1){
            s = parseFloat(s).toFixed(3) * 1000;
        }else if(s.indexOf('M') >-1){
            s = parseFloat(s).toFixed(3) * 1000000;
        }else if(s.indexOf('B') >-1){
            s = parseFloat(s).toFixed(3) * 1000000000;
        }

        // format your data for normalization
        return s;
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text
    type: 'numeric'
});

$(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            3: {
                sorter:'marketcap' // sorting (4th column with parser)
            }
        }
    });
});
```